# Firebase Security Rules for Blog like apps

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am just playing with firebase, storing user blog posts, and count of likes and dislikes,

I am storing post under 
`/posts/$uid/$key`
(eg:  `/posts/XFSDFSFSDFSDF/-KKm1gBQRivx1x-thh8m`)

And to query all posts I also store same data in `/timeline/$key`
(eg:  `/timeline/-KKm1gBQRivx1x-thh8m`)

Similar for like and dislike, my security rules is something like this.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "posts":{
      "$uid":{
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "timeline":{
      "$key":{
        ".validate": "root.child('posts/'+ auth.uid +'/'+$key).exists()",
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
    },
    "user-likes": {
      "$uid":{
        "$post":{
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".validate":"root.child('timeline/'+$post).exists() && newData.child('type').exists()"
        }
      }
    },
    "likes": {
      "$post":{
        "$key":{
          ".validate": "root.child('user-likes/'+ auth.uid +'/'+$post+'/'+$key+'/  type').val()==newData.child('type').val()",
          ".write": "auth != null",
          ".indexOn": ["type"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there is any problem with save data twice? Is there any other better solution for this?